# What to do in xcode 13 after company invites me as developer?

Tags: xcode, developer-program

Getting started on a new MacBook with Xcode 13:

- I've just accepted the invitaion from my company as a developer with my Apple-ID.
- I logged in to my Apple-ID at XCode 13 -> Preferences -> Tab: Accounts.
- I expected to select a 'Team' with the 'Role' 'Developer', but there us only the 'Personal Team' with the 'Role' 'User'

Since I was invited as a developer and accepted the invite, I expect a team with the developer role to be available.
Only If I choose such role I can put the apps I develop on an iPhone.

What do I neeed to do to build and deploy a new iOS project on my iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

Start by verifying that you are a part of the development team of the said company.

1. Visit https://developer.apple.com and login with your Apple ID.
2. Click on your name in the top right corner and make sure that the said company is listed as one of the options.

   [image]
3. If not, go back to your invitation email try accepting the invite again.
4. Go to Xcode preferences -> Accounts, try by removing and adding your Apple ID.
5. If you still do not see the said company, try contacting the Account Holder and check if you still have the access.

**Update**: After adding your Apple ID in Xcode, you can set the development team correctly as shown below:

[image]

Comment: yes the company name is listed there. It's actually the only thing right under my name so there is nothing to choose.

Comment: The account holder can see my Apple-ID in the section Users -> Developer

Comment: @Human Did you try the steps mentioned and are you able to see the company name in Xcode preferences?

Comment: yes @Nimesh, my comments were a directed to your answer. I went there and saw the company name. I also made sure that the company listed me as a developer. Unfortunately I was still not able to select the Developer Team.

Comment: @Human Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I cant see the team of the company there only "Personal"